# DomCrawler get element contents after specific element

Tags: php, laravel, web-scraping, domcrawler

I'm trying to get an element's contents that comes right after another element. Here's some example code:

```
<header>2010</header>
<div>
    <a href="">Some data</a>
    <a href="">Some data</a>
</div>
<header>2011</header>
<div>
    <a href="">Some data</a>
    <a href="">Some data</a>
</div>
```

I need to get the data sorted by years and I've tried something, but for 2010 it takes the data for all years.

```
$crawler->filter('header')->each(function(Crawler $c) {
$year = $c->text();
$next = $c->nextAll();
$next->filter('div a')->each(function($node){
    $node->text();
});
});
```

How do I make it stop after getting all `div a`s between the two headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case you can take only **first** node from `nextAll` and as this first item is `div`, filter just `a` in it:

```
$crawler->filter('header')->each(function(Crawler $c) {
    $year = $c->text();
    dump($year);
    $next = $c->nextAll()->first();
    $next->filter('a')->each(function($node){
        dump($node->text());
    });
});
```